# Using social login to access private API

Tags: api, oauth, facebook-login

I m building a website and a mobile application where both of them uses common resources from my server using APIs. Is it possible to use Social Login like Facebook / Twitter / Gmail to authenticate users to use my application? This will benefit me by not creating my own security layer and rely entirely on their security mechanism to secure my APIs.

OAuth documentation states that **Users** grant access to their **Protected Resources** without sharing their credentials with the **Consumer**.

In my case, by giving **Login via Facebook**, I want these Facebook **Users** to login to my application and use the **Protected Resources** which are exposed by my APIs.

Let me know if I am on the right track or not ? How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use Facebook (or Google+) for a login mechanism on your website.

Facebook offers a button for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Here´s more information about the Facebook login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

If you don´t want to use the Login Social Plugin, the best way is to use the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Google+ offers a login button too: https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in

I did not use the Google+ solution yet, but with the Facebook login it´s quite easy. You can just store the Facebook ID for registration and stuff.

Comment: The question is how do I access my service APIs Securely using Social  login like Facebook. Facebook Login allows you to login and get access to Facebook resources which is fine. Further, I would like to use the token to access my server resources in a secure manner.

Comment: with the php sdk this is very easy, see the example code: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk. you can just restrict access to specific parts of your page by checking if the user id is valid: $user = $facebook->getUser();